# Algorithm with chapter number

Tags: algorithm2e

I want the algorithm to be prefix with chapter
say in chapter 1, it should be 1.1, 1.2, for chapter 2, it should be 2.1, 2.2

But for my case, i only have 1,2,3,... across all chapters, how should I change it?

The include package is listed as followed:

```
\usepackage[ruled,vlined,linesnumbered,algo2e,resetcount,algochapter]{algorithm2e}
```

Here is the minimal working example

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{moreverb}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{dsfont}


\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage{ctable}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{moreverb}
\usepackage{scalefnt}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, positioning, fit, calc}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\usepackage{scalefnt}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usetikzlibrary{
    shapes.geometric,
    positioning,
    fit,
    calc
}
\usepackage{amsmath}



\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata,positioning,shapes,patterns}

\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage{amsmath, url, proof} % mathabx,
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined,linesnumbered,algo2e,resetcount,algochapter]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usetikzlibrary{trees,decorations.pathmorphing}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scaled]{beramono}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%






\def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-dvipdfm.def}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata,positioning}
\usepackage{epsf}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts} %
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{ltlfonts}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{chngcntr}

\usepackage{latexsym} % latex symbols
\usepackage{amsthm} % for defining theorems
\usepackage{syntonly} % verify syntax, not very important
\usepackage{lscape} 

\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}% http://ctan.org/pkg/subcaption
\captionsetup{compatibility=false}
\DeclareCaptionSubType*{algorithm}
\renewcommand\thesubalgorithm{\thetable\alph{subalgorithm}}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{alglabel}{Alg.~#2}


\usepackage{pxfonts, pifont} % About fonts
\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{multirow} % To write complicated tables
\usepackage{colortbl} % Colors
\usepackage{rotating} % For rotating tables

\usepackage{verbatim} % Comment Environment
                      % eg. \begin{comment}
                      %     \end{comment}

\usepackage{mdwlist}

%%

\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}

\usepackage{url}

\usepackage{style/mythesis}
\usepackage{lscape}

\usepackage{listings}
\newcommand{\myfontsize}{\fontsize{9}{10}\selectfont}
\usepackage[backref=section,colorlinks=true,hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}
  \hypersetup{
            colorlinks,%
            citecolor=black,%
            filecolor=black,%
            linkcolor=black,%
            urlcolor=black,breaklinks = true, %
            pdfprintscaling = None, %
            unicode = true, %
            bookmarksnumbered = true,
      }


\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\interfootnotelinepenalty=10000







\begin{document}


\newpage
\pagenumbering{roman}
\singlespacing{ \listofalgorithms
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\numberline{}\hspace{-.35in}{\bf List
of Algorithms}}} 

\doublespacing



\chapter{chapter1}~\label{a1}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\centering
a
\caption{algo}\label{algo1}
\end{algorithm}

\chapter{chapter2}~\label{a2}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\centering
a
\caption{algo}\label{algo2}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\centering
a
\caption{algo}\label{algo3}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I get the numbering you wish to; please, add a minimal example.

Comment: @egreg have updated with minimal working example

Comment: The problem is that you're also loading the `algorithm` package and the `algorithm` environment is taken from this. Use `algorithm2e` environment and you will solve. Anyway try to remove all unnecessary packages you're loading.

Comment: Add this to your preamble, after loading the packages: `\makeatletter
\renewcommand\thealgorithm{\thechapter.\arabic{algorithm}}
\@addtoreset{algorithm}{chapter}
\makeatother`

Comment: @GonzaloMedina It works! May be you would wish to post as an answer :)

Comment: @william007 done!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since you are using both the `algorithm2e` and `algorithm` packages, and both of them implement some same commands/environments, you had to use the `algo2e` option for `algorithm2e` to prevent a clash and this overrides the settings for the counter that you set as options for `algorith2e`, since the environment that will be used is the one from `algorithm`. You have three possible solutions:

1. If you don't need the `algorithm` package, load only `algorithm2e` and not `algorithm` and load the former *without* the `algo2e` option:

   ```
   \documentclass[11pt]{book}
   \usepackage[ruled,vlined,linesnumbered,resetcount,algochapter]{algorithm2e}

   \begin{document}

   \chapter{chapter1}
   \begin{algorithm}[H]
   \centering
   test
   \caption{algo}
   \label{algo1}
   \end{algorithm}

   \end{document}
   ```

   [image]
2. If you *really* need both `algorithm2e` and `algorithm` in your document, and you want to use the `algorithm` environment (from the `algorithm` package) add the following lines to your preamble, after loading the packages:

   ```
   \makeatletter 
   \renewcommand\thealgorithm{\thechapter.\arabic{algorithm}} 
   \@addtoreset{algorithm}{chapter} 
   \makeatother
   ```

   A complete example:

   ```
   \documentclass[11pt]{book}
   \usepackage[ruled,vlined,linesnumbered,algo2e,resetcount,algochapter]{algorithm2e}
   \usepackage{algorithm}

   \makeatletter 
   \renewcommand\thealgorithm{\thechapter.\arabic{algorithm}} 
   \@addtoreset{algorithm}{chapter} 
   \makeatother

   \begin{document}

   \chapter{chapter1}
   \begin{algorithm}[H]
   \centering
   test
   \caption{algo}
   \label{algo1}
   \end{algorithm}

   \end{document}
   ```

   [image]
3. If you *really* need both `algorithm2e` and `algorithm` in your document, and you want to use the `algorithm` environment (from the `algorithm2e` package), use the `algorithm2e` environment (the `algo2e` option renames `algorithm` to `algorithm2e`):

   ```
   \documentclass[11pt]{book}
   \usepackage[ruled,vlined,linesnumbered,algo2e,resetcount,algochapter]{algorithm2e}
   \usepackage{algorithm}

   \begin{document}

   \chapter{chapter1}
   \begin{algorithm2e}[H]
   \centering
   test
   \caption{algo}
   \label{algo1}
   \end{algorithm2e}

   \end{document}
   ```

[image]

By the way (not related to the question), you are loading packages more than once; this should be avoided.

Comment: For your solution in (2), how can I add `:` after the algorithm number? This can be found at your solution in (3).

Comment: Asked this queston to follow-up https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/554151/38244

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `\ counterwithin` command, originally defined by the `chngcntr` package, but in basic latex nowadays. I also use `caption` to add separator between the caption label and the caption text:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\counterwithin{algorithm}{chapter}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[algorithm]{labelsep=colon, textfont=it}

\begin{document}

\chapter{chapter1}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\centering
test
\caption{algo}
\label{algo1}
\end{algorithm}

This where we refer to Algorithm \ref{algo1}.
\end{document}
```

[image]